# Beautiful problem of a set of a,b,c.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A set of a,b,c was changed to this set: $a^4-2b^2, b^4-2c^2, c^4-2a^2$. It happened that these two sets are identical. Find a,b,c, if a+b+c=-3.

$a^2(a^2-2)+b^2(b^2-2)+c^2(c^2-2)=a+b+c=-3$ I guess, but what next though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: the premise implies
$$
0=3+a+b+c=3+(a^4-2b^2)+(b^4-2c^2)+(c^4-2a^2)\\
=(a^2-1)^2+(b^2-1)^2+(c^2-1)^2.
$$
What now can you say about $a^2,b^2$, and $c^2$?

Comment: wow this is cool, now a=+-1, b=+-1, c=+-1 follows

Comment: Remember the condition that sum is -3, what can you conclude?

Comment: oh yes now a=-1,b=-1,c=-1